# How can I pass command line arguments to a program via Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to use my `args` array.

I mean this array:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Where can I run something like `java Test one two three`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the run configuration section. [Here](http://www.javapassion.com/handsonlabs/commandarguments/index.html#Exercise_2) is how.

Comment: Unfortunately this link is no longer correct. It throws 404 for me :(

Answer (score 3):

Check the properties of the java project. There you see the menu item "Run"
There you can specify arguments for you commandline.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the project properties (either File -> Project properties or richt click on the project in he projects list on the left), select "Run" and there you can set it.

Comment: can I enable assertions on the Vm options box?